# How can I display my dynamic image as a background?

Tags: html, css, django

I am developing a django aplication, which is a simple website where I can put many images dynamically, from my admin site(models). I know how to display these images in my html template with one loop, but I don't know how I can display these images as background or header in my html template. Have anyone a idea how my html would be? Have I to use css to do it?

.html(only the way I use to display my image)

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class=item>
            <p>{{ post.nome_hotel }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.apresentacao_hotel }}</p>
            <picture>{% cloudinary post.foto_hotel %}</picture>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So you want like this? https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index2.html

Comment: Yeah, but I dont know if these images were put dynamically with admin site (models). If yes, I would like to know how I can do this.

Comment: Surelly you can do this :) Make Photo models and make view that returns Photo.objects.all() to your HTML to render :)

Comment: Yes, I did it, but I dont know how I can put this imagem in my background.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is how to use django template language to do it, or just the html part? You're using your own html code or using a template taken from somewhere else?.

If the first is the case, I would recommend using for example a bootstrap template http://getbootstrap.com/, and instead of writing your own html/css, use one of the templates (if you search will find hundreds) as boilerplate.

Comment: I have a Django projecto works fine, I would like to know how to create a HTML whose I can do the dynamic image as a background. Yeah, I am trying to create a html whose I can do this. So, my problem is only HTML.

Comment: I'd suggest then to post the question as html/css related, not django, since no django code is involved.
Regarding the html, I would use a bootstrap template like this one for exmple https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/, all the html and css code needed is there, you just have to point your source images and it works.

Comment: My source image is variable, because I had to make a loop to put this. I dont know how to set this variable image as a background.

Comment: {% for post in posts %}
  <div class=item>
   <p>{{ post.nome_hotel }}</p>
   <p>{{ post.apresentacao_hotel }}</p>
   <picture>{% cloudinary post.foto_hotel %}</picture>
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
this is the way that I display my image. How can I display this as a background?